# angular 2 form validation not working using hash form element

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I have one form validation using angular 2.[Angular 2 Only] How to start validation part using below the way?

app.component.html:

```
<form   #registrationForm="ngForm"  (ngSubmit)="submitform()">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" formControlName="name" />
</form>
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder,FormGroup,Validators } from '@angular/forms';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  ngForm: FormGroup;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.ngForm = this._fb.group({
      name: ['Select', Validators.required]
    });
  }
  submitform() {
    this.formSubmitted = true;
    if (!this.ngForm.valid) {
      alert("Form Not valid");
    } else {
      alert("Valid");
    }
  }
}
```

Above the script is not working..Where i did mistake?

Comment: What are you expecting? I think it should be `(submit)` instead of `(ngSubmit)`

Comment: Why are you using  `#registrationForm="ngForm"` when you are using [Reactive Forms]( #registrationForm="ngForm"). Also you should probably avoid calling your `FormGroup` `ngForm`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an Issue with your Template. Instead of using `#registrationForm="ngForm"` use `[formGroup]="ngForm"`

You're using a Reactive Form approach and in that, to map the form on the template, with the form on the Component, you use `[formGroup]` on the `form` tag in your template.

`#registrationForm="ngForm"` is generally used in the Template Drive strategy of building forms. Then on `(submit)` you also pass the form to the method which isn't really required in this case.

Also, you should be using `(submit)` instead of `(ngSubmit)`

Try this:

```
<form [formGroup]="ngForm" (submit)="submitform()">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" formControlName="name" />
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-form-eg-valid?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: Please use like this:   <form   #registrationForm="ngForm"  (ngSubmit)="submitform()">

Comment: I am waiting for your answer

Comment: @SEERANSV, `<form #registrationForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submitform()">` is generally used in Template Driven Forms. Since you're using a Reactive Form, and you'll already have the Form's JavaScript representation, in your Component Class, you don't really need to do `<form #registrationForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submitform()">`

Comment: Thanks you so mcuh

Comment: @ SiddAjmera     Can you answer this issue?  How to fetch json data and show?https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular2-notifications-example-awkttw?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: Can u answer this qa?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52948230/template-form-validation-angular

Answer (score 0):

what are you trying to validate? there is only one input field, if you want to validate that try putting 'required' attribute or condition to validate on the input field. 
Also, if you need to take a look at simple form validation example, check the following repo:
https://github.com/alokstar/Angular4FormValidation

Hope it helps!

Comment: these questions are generally posted in comments instead of as an answer.